# A is irrelevant to B "or" or "nor" C?

Tags: grammar, logic

If I want to convey A is irrelevant to B, and A is irrelevant to C.
Should I say:

```
A is irrelevant to B or C.
```

Or

```
A is irrelevant to B nor C.
```

Or any other expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you need a separate "negative polarity" element in your sentence (or your multi-sentence thought) to trigger the use of *nor*.  These would be words such as *No*, *not*, *never*, *nothing*, or *neither*; a negating prefix like *ir-*, *non-* or *de-* is not enough to make a *nor* show up in standard use.

So you could say

> A is irrelevant to either B or C
>
> A is irrelevant to B and to C
>
> A is relevant to neither B nor C
>
> A is not relevant to B nor C
>
> Nothing in A is relevant to B; nor is it relevant to C.
>
> There is no relevance between A and B, nor between A and C

Some "high-formality" uses of *nor* by itself intend for the *neither* to be implied:

> *A is relevant to B nor C* == "A is relevant to neither B nor C"

But this is an uncommon construction these days and should probably be avoided, as many people will construe it to be an error.

Answer (score 2):

This question can be answered logically.

> A is irrelevant to B and C.

or (more awkwardly):

> A is relevant to neither B nor C.